# Should I install Jupyter Notebook in the base env or project env?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm having some trouble decide how to go about installing Jupyter Notebook on my Mac.

I'm running macOS Catalina and used Home-brew to install python3. I understand that I could have easily installed Anaconda and as a result have Jupyter out of the box. However, I don't want to use Anaconda for package management, and I'd rather stick with pip.

My question is, should I now "pip install jupyter" in my base environment, or should I install it everytime I create a virtualenv for a new project?

Comment: "I'd rather stick with pip." You can use pip along with Anaconda.

Comment: Anis, can I download Jupyter via Anaconda, and continue to use pip for package management?

Comment: Yes, you can. Anconda comes with Jupyter included btw.